# Разбиение строки на слова

Tags: pascal

Есть строка (s), в ней идут слова через пробел. Нужно занести все слова в массив. И посчитать, сколько раз оно  встречается  в  данной  строке (s).
Я так заносил в массив.

```
lastid:=1;
j:=1;
for i:=1 to length(s) do
if (s[i]=' ') then 
begin
a[j]:=copy(s,lastid,i-lastid);
lastid:=i+1;
inc(j);
end;
a[j]:=copy(s,lastid,length(s)-lastid+1);
```

Comment: а "И посчитать, сколько раз оно встречается в данной строке (s)"
Лучше находить pos'ом  начало этого слова в строке, и удалять в строке символы до этого начала слова + длинна слова. И выполнять это до того как pos не вернёт 0

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать побыстрее и использовать не перебор всех символов, а сразу искать пробел через PosEx(' ',s,lastid)

Comment: Нет, не быстрее, PosEx ищет также перебором, по другому никак :)

Comment: Возможно и быстрее, потому что он может (если сделан по уму) таскать из строки сразу по 2-4-8 байт и шлепать масками.